# Where can I find a reference for all the syntax that's supported with git commit hashes?

Tags: git

Is there a specific reference for all this (and maybe more):

```
1c91230a18f~
1c91230a18f^
1c91230a18f{^,}
1c91230a18f~10
1c91230a18f~!
```

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection

Comment: @zerkms nor `~!` nor `{~,}` is there.

Comment: @zerkms oh nice! as if I didn't do that...

Comment: now I'm curious what google queries you tried that didn't lead you to anything relevant. Anything I try leads to some sort of correct documentation.

Comment: @zerkms: https://www.google.com.br/search?q=git+hash+syntax

Comment: @zerkms: and https://www.google.com.br/search?q=git+hash+tilde

Comment: first query #2, #3, #4 and #6? second query first link?

Comment: @zerkms that's the link you sent me, at last in my results, and it's incomplete.

Comment: it's not complete but: 1. it provides you the correct terminology for further search 2. it explains half of your question

Comment: @zerkms it also surprises me that you didn't mention `man` and instead provided another link to another web copy of man-pages.

Comment: I showed you how to fish, it's more valuable.

Comment: The 3 of us all contributed to come up with the answer below, that others can use for reference, so we can be glad about that. :)

Comment: @zerkms as if twasbrillig's initial useful link didn't show upfront it's was a `man` scan.

Comment: @pepper_chico for anyone who know about `man` it's obvious that http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html is a mirror to the `man gitrevisions`

Comment: @zerkms it's obvious from twasbrillig link contents too. I just hope some moderator delete this conversation entirely since the google-fu mockery started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This webpage: http://schacon.github.io/git/gitrevisions.html lists a lot of them.

### Update:

http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html is the same page but with a preferable domain, thanks @zerkms.

And it can be found using `man gitrevisions`, thanks @pepper_chico.

Comment: It's `man gitrevisions`. Now I know the command, if you care to update to use `man`instead of web reference, it's a better answer.